# Simplifying the second derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fractions, implicit-differentiation

I need to simplify the below with respect to $y''$. I'm given: $$y''=-\frac{3x^2y^3-3x^3y^2\left(-\frac{x^3}{y^3}\right)}{y^6}$$

The final result should look like:
$$-\frac{3x^2(y^4+x^4)}{y^7}$$

Here are my steps:

1. Combine term: $-3x^3y^2\left(-\frac{x^3}{y^3}\right)$.
   $$-3x^3y^2\left(-\frac{x^3}{y^3}\right)=\frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3}$$
   Our expression is now:
   $$y''=-\frac{3x^2y^3+\frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3}}{y^6}$$
2. Multiply the final term in the numerator, $\frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3}$, by the it's reciprocal in the denominator, $\frac{y^6}{1}$, to eliminate the complex fraction.
   $$\frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3} * \frac{y^6}{1}=\frac{3x^6y^8}{y^3}$$
   Our expression is now:
   $$y''=-\frac{3x^2y^3}{y^6}+\frac{3x^6y^8}{y^3}$$
3. Multiply term $\frac{3x^6y^8}{y^3}$ by $\frac{y^3}{y^3}$ to make common denominators.
   $$\frac{3x^6y^8}{y^3}*\frac{y^3}{y^3}=\frac{3x^6y^{11}}{y^6}$$
   Our separate terms can now be added, and our expression will look like:
   $$y''=-\frac{3x^2y^3+3x^6y^{11}}{y^6}$$
4. Now factor the numerator, our expression will become:
   $$y''=-\frac{3x^2y^3(1+x^4y^{8})}{y^6}$$

Have I made a mistake? I'm not sure where to go from here. I need to achieve this expression as stated at the top my question:
$$y''=-\frac{3x^2(y^4+x^4)}{y^7}$$

Comment: how comes you to the second derivative?

Comment: step 2 needs fixing

Comment: Division by a number is the same as multiplying by 1/(that number)

Comment: i have the same result as you

Comment: @baverso Why not cancel out a $y^2$ factor at step 1 in $\frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3}$.

Comment: @dr.sonnhardgraubner the problem above is the second half of an example problem from the textbook which I'll cite below. Both what I have given, and the final answers come from the textbook. The textbook is James Stewart's Calculus Early Transcendentals 7th Edition, page 213.

Comment: @randomgirl I agree but if I want to cancel a complex fraction I can do so by multiplying by the denominator's reciprocal. I don't believe step 2 is incorrect?

Comment: @dxiv I definitely could do that. It's definitely a valid move. But for the purpose of understanding and learning from the algebraic path I've already taken, I'd prefer to work with The steps that have been performed. If the algebra is correct, I should still reach the same simplification as the textbook right?

Comment: @baverso That's right, but delaying obvious simplifications keeps the expressions unnecessarily complicated, and increases the chance of errors. In your case the error is at the very next step, as pointed out already: $$\frac{\frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3}}{y^6}=\frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3}\cdot \frac{1}{y^6} \ne \frac{3x^6y^2}{y^3}\cdot \frac{y^6}{1}$$

Comment: I agree with you 100% on the expression above. However, we're not rewriting the complex fraction. We are multiplying the complex numerator by the reciprocal of the denominator to eliminate that denominator.

Comment: @baverso Sorry, I don't follow that. Simple fact is that $\frac{a}{b} = a \cdot \frac{1}{b}$. You can write it directly, or derive it as $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a \,\cdot\, 1/b}{b \,\cdot\, 1/b}=\frac{a \,\cdot\, 1/b}{1} = a \cdot \frac{1}{b}$ *but* no matter how you do it, you'll never end up with $a \cdot \frac{b}{1}$ instead. `We are multiplying the complex numerator by the reciprocal of the denominator` If I read that right, the denominator is $y^6$ so its "reciprocal" is $\frac{1}{y^6}$ *not* $\frac{y^6}{1}\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''=-\frac{3x^2y^3-3x^3y^2\left(-\frac{x^3}{y^3}\right)}{y^6}=-\frac{3x^2y^3+3x^3\left(\frac{x^3}{y}\right)}{y^6}=y''=-\frac{\left(\frac{3x^2y^4+3x^6}{y}\right)}{y^6}=-\frac{3x^2y^4+3x^6}{y^7}=-\frac{3x^2(y^4+x^4)}{y^7}$$

Comment: How does $3x^2y^3$ become $3x^2y^4$?

Comment: $3x^2y^3+\frac{3x^6}{y}=\frac{3x^2y^4}{y}+\frac{3x^6}{y}=\frac{3x^2y^4+3x^6}{y}$. did you get it?

Comment: Not quite. What raises the power of $y$ in $3x^2y^3$ to become $3x^2y^4$ in the numerator? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok I see. We are multiplying by $y/y$. Thanks

Comment: You are very welcome.